# How to find the left cosets of a group?

Tags: group-theory

Given the group $G=(\mathbb{Z}_{12},+)$ and a subgroup $H=\langle[4]\rangle$, list the left cosets of $H$.

All that I understand about (left) cosets is that $x\sim y\iff x=yh$ where $h\in H$. I don't know how to 'calculate' them though.

The answers that were given for this question are as follows:

- $[1]+H=\{[1],[5],[9]\}$
- $[2]+H=\{[2],[6],[10]\}$
- $[3]+H=\{[3],[7],[11]\}$

I can see from context how these sets were calculated ($[1]+[0]=[1]$, and so on).. but how were $[1], [2], [3]$ chosen to be added with the elements of $H$?

Comment: They were going in order, from 1 to 12. For example, you could write $[6]+H$ instead of $[2]+H$ but this is much more elegant..And because this relation you wrote is relation of equivalence, you know that you've got all left cosets when union of them gives you the whole group..

Answer (score 3):

1) We know that $\mathbb{Z}_{12}=\{0,1,2,3,\cdots,11\}$ and $H=\{0,4,8\}$ and we are working with abelian finite groups.

2) The group is finite of order $12$ so we have $\big|\frac{\mathbb{Z}_{12}}{H}\big|=\frac{12}{3}=4$.

3) The quotient group $\frac{\mathbb{Z}_{12}}{H}$ is $\{gH|g\in\mathbb{Z}_{12}\}=\{g+H|g\in\mathbb{Z}_{12}\}$ and know that $$g+H=\{g+h|h\in H\}$$

4) We learned that if suddenly $g\in H$ then $g+H=H$ which is $e_{\frac{\mathbb{Z}_{12}}{H}}$.

5) So we have, finally, $$\frac{\mathbb{Z}_{12}}{H}=\{1+H,2+H,3+H, 5+H, 6+H, 7+H, 9+H,10+H, 11+H\}$$

6) Now, lets to do some handy calculations. What is $9+H$? It is $$\{9+0,9+4,9+8\}=\{9,1,5\}=\{1+8,1+0,1+4\}=1+H$$

7) Do the same way to find your final answer.